# Is it safe to put a baking steel directly on oven's floor?

Tags: oven, kitchen-safety

I have an electric [oven](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/products/appliances/ovens/tj%C3%A4nlig-forced-air-oven-stainless-steel-art-40300803/) with concealed heating elements, I am considering putting my baking steel directly on the oven's floor for the purpose of doing some cooking experiments.
Is this safe?
Would it damage the oven?
Manual [here](http://www.ikea.com/gb/en/doc/advice_and_instructions/tj%C3%A4nlig__aa-1513580-4.pdf).

Comment: I would not do that but I don't have facts to back it up.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual? What is the make and model?

Comment: Is there any heating element on the bottom? If not, I have done this several times in a similar oven and nothing happened. Any reason for believing it can be a problem?

Comment: @greedyscholars  There is a heating element on the bottom, but that is concealed under the floor oven. .

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk there is a link to the manual in the question text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the manual specifically mentions not dragging anything across the bottom, this implies to me that objects can be rested there, as long as they are carefully set in place and removed.

Comment: nice observation and good point!